# Generating all digit strings of constant length

Tags: python, python-2.7

What would be the easiest way to generate all the digit strings of a constant length?

Lets say length == 3, so all the strings would be:

000

001

002

...

010

011

etc...

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. Although homework is not off topic, we expect you to show some effort. What code have you tried so far? What problems did you run into while implementing your solution?

Comment: Show what you've tried. SO is not a programming service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works for any given `n` - the expected length of the output:

```
def generate(n):
    return [str(x).zfill(n) for x in xrange(10**n)]
```

For example:

```
generate(2)
=> ['00', '01', '02', ... , '97', '98', '99']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create all numbers of that length (0 to 10**length). Then convert them to strings with string.format(). The option `0:<length>` makes sure they get appended to the correct number of zeroes.

```
def fun(length):
    form = '{:0'+str(length)+'}'
    return [form.format(n) for n in range(10**length)]

In [1]: fun(2)
Out[1]: 
['00',
 '01',
 '02',
 '03',
 '04',
 '05',
 '06',
 '07',
 '08',
 '09',
...
```